Achieve Similar Arrays in Minimum Number of Steps
I am trying to solve one of my assignment problems.
The following is the problem statement-

Given an array A and a target array, your task is to make A similar to the target array.
Two arrays are considered similar if the frequency of each element is the same. For example, the arrays [1,1,1,3,3,4] and [3,4,1,1,3,1] are similar. However, the arrays [1,2,3,4] and [1,1,2,3] are not similar - the frequency of 4 in the first array is 1, while in the second array it is 0.
You are only allowed to perform certain operations on the array. As part of one operation, you will:
● select two indices (i,j) (no constraints on i and j).
● Increment the element at the ith position by 2: A[i] = A[i]+2
● Decrement the element at the jth position by 2: A[j] = A[j]-2
You can only perform operations on the array A.
You cannot perform partial operations - that is, you have to increment the element at i, and simultaneously decrement the element at j, you cannot do one of the two.
If it is not possible to make the array A similar to the target array, return -1; otherwise return the minimum number of operations to make A similar to the target.

I've only been able to make very elementary observations till now.
Like, since we are adding and subtracting 2 simultaneously, the array sum will remain constant.
So if sum(A_List)!=sum(Target_List) then return -1
Further, since each operation increments one element by 2 and decrements another by 2, the range of elements in the array A can only increase or decrease by a multiple of 2. This means that if there is an element in the target array whose value cannot be obtained by incrementing or decrementing elements in A by a multiple of 2, it is impossible to make A similar to the target array.
I can't wrap my head around how I should proceed.

Think about parity conservation and you might be able to make some progress.

sum(A)!=sum(Target) - this doesn't work, completely different numbers could gain the same sum

@MartinBrown can you please elaborate further?

Adding or subtracting 2 doesn't change whether a number is odd or even. This gives you a very quick way to rule out all the clearly impossible dissimilar cases.
